# What are the consequences of cancelling/ending my German work visa?

Tags: germany, working-visas, resident-permit, work-permit

For various reasons, I am considering giving up my work visa / residence permit in Germany, and returning to my home country. After some initial research, I'm struggling to fully understand the consequences of doing so. Some specifics I'm still unsure of:

- Will this prevent me from applying for the same visa/permit again in future?

  - If so, is there a time limit until I can apply again?
  - If not, will it still make the process *harder* in future?
- Could you share any tips on the process in general? Any pitfalls to avoid.

If you can clarify any one of these points for me, that would be very helpful. Thank you.